# Labels not getting printed in line charts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image]I have a pandas dataframe in this format:

```
            Act               Pred
 date
2019-11     100               65
2019-12     86                65
```

When I plot the line graph,

```
    df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
    ax = df.plot(kind="line")
    ax.savefig("graph1.png"
```

I don't get the dates in x axis. It's just 2 lines in the line graph. I don't see the dates `"2019-11"` and `"2019-12"` in the x-axis.

Am I missing any parameter for it?

[image]

Comment: `ax` does not have `savefig` method. If you mean `fig.savefig`, then it works as expected for me.

Comment: @QuangHoang: What is fig?

Comment: @user3447653 `fig` is `matplotlib.figure.Figure`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its the field type not posting correctly. I converted it to a date field and was able to get X axis markers.
`df["date"] = df["date"].astype('datetime64[ns]')`

Comment: Now instead of 2 dates, i get the graph (replaced the original graph)